# Что такое Sample Data Directory?

Tags: kotlin

Пытаюсь создать папку res -> new -> Sample Data Directory.

Подскажите пожалуйста что это такое и в чем от Anroid Recource Directory?

Comment: как это относится к котлину?

Comment: Не дали добавить вторую метку "android studio". А к Котлину это относиться, т.к. пишу код на Котлин в Андройд Студио.

Comment: Вопрос не относится ни к котлину, ни к Андроид студии.

Comment: Ну ладно.. что делать тогда, куда переносить вопрос?)

Comment: Да никуда не переносить, пусть лежит :)